# How can I add user info to conv.user.storage?

Tags: webhooks, google-assistant-sdk, actions-builder

I'm using Actions Builder to create my chatbot and after user logins using Google I want to save his ID to storage variable.
This storage variable doesn't exist on conv.user.
So I do this:

```
if (conv.user.verificationStatus === 'VERIFIED') {
  conv.user.storage = {};
  conv.user.storage.id = str.rows[0].id;
  console.log("STORAGE");
  console.log(conv.user.storage.id);
}
```

But on Google Assistant it returns the error message and on my Webhook it's all good (no errors shown):
[Google Assistant Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxz90.png)

What can I do to save/persist at least my user ID for future referings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since user has the Google Sign In process done once, every time he enters in your action you have his info on the request (payload). It´s automatically added to user storage.

You should store it on conv.user.params and refer to it in your code.

You may have a *get* and *set* method to help you with:

```
getUserId(conv) {
    return conv.user.params.userId;
}

setUserId(conv, userId) {
    try {
        conv.user.params.userId = userId;
    } catch (e) {
        throw new error("Error setting USERID");
    }

    return userId;
}
```